# Get product list from Huawei In app purchase

Tags: flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

So, i want to get my products list from my Huawei developer account, i integrate the sdk and all it's fine. the issue here in this code :

```
Future<List<ProductInfo>> getConsumableProducts() async {
try {
  ProductInfoReq req = ProductInfoReq(); // The named parameter 'skuIds' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argumentThe named parameter 'priceType' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argument
  req.priceType = IapClient.IN_APP_CONSUMABLE;
  req.skuIds = ["prod_01", "prod_02"];
  ProductInfoResult res = await IapClient.obtainProductInfo(req);
  return res.productInfoList; // A value of type 'List<ProductInfo>?' can't be returned from the method 'getConsumableProducts' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<ProductInfo>>'
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  log(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

i mention the issues in the code. P.S : i made a search and verify that this code is the same code which public

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain purchase information, you could follow the code below:

```
List<String> productIdList = new ArrayList<>();
// Only those products already configured in AppGallery Connect can be queried.
productIdList.add("ConsumeProduct1001");
ProductInfoReq req = new ProductInfoReq();
// priceType: 0: consumable; 1: non-consumable; 2: subscription
req.setPriceType(0);
req.setProductIds(productIdList);
// Obtain the Activity object that calls the API.
final Activity activity = getActivity();
// Call the obtainProductInfo API to obtain the details of the product configured in AppGallery Connect.
Task<ProductInfoResult> task = Iap.getIapClient(activity).obtainProductInfo(req);
```

Check [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/dev-guide-0000001050130254) for more info.